# Weird song from liner notes of a broken CD

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual

Grandpa Bob liked to think he was a rockstar. He also loved to play that play-a-song-and-guess-the-name game. Known outside the family exclusively as Mr Deau, the weirdest thing he left behind when he died was a self-recorded album on CD. I can't seem to get the CD to play - all I have is the liner notes, with what I assume are the lyrics for one track on each page, along with some art.

One of the pages is weird. I've scanned it and put it here. If you ask me, the lyrics seem practically meaningless, but I feel that if I could only hear Grandpa's recording, with the pitchless cacophony that was his voice singing to the beat, I might be able to figure out the song's name at least, if not its meaning. I wouldn't be surprised if the old fella stuck his own name in there too, somehow.

So I ask you, please, to help me. *Can you get the CD to play this track, and tell me what is the name of this song?*

---

[image: Song]

---

**Hint**:

> *One of Grandpa Bob's old friends was one of those 'rock music is evil' conspiracy theorists. Bob thought he was a loon, but reckoned he got some inspiration from his ideas sometimes.*
>
> As a side note, guessing from the genes I inherited from him, I don't think Grandpa Bob was blessed with great singing ability. I'm sure he did his best at making this track, but for all his efforts he did make some mistakes - if you figure out the crux of the puzzle, don't second guess yourself by getting too hung up on vocal inaccuracies. They are not where the solution to the puzzle lies.

---

**Hint 2**:

> Among Grandpa Bob's possessions when he died, we found a number of records, including the Beatles' *White Album* and their single *Paperback Writer*, Pink Floyd's album *The Wall*, and "Weird Al" Yankovic's *Bad Hair Day*.

---

**Hint 3**:

> Some astute puzzlers (especially @LannyStrack) have analysed this interesting track to the point of realizing that Grandpa's vocals sound (as far as he could manage with his limited singing ability) the same played forwards or backwards, making the song an audible palindrome. I'm convinced he did this for a reason, perhaps to show us how to look for meaning in the strange song. I can't help but notice also that all analysis hitherto has focused on his vocals, leaving half the contents of the track by the wayside. Perhaps Grandpa's palindromic vocals merely hint towards an analysis of the rest of the song...

Comment: For those who can't read the liner notes, the lyrics are as follows (as printed): Oh, your face it is switching o' me/A boat on water - Yes!/Oh, you know I saw your law/My will was seeming inert? Oh yeah!/I want to know, why are you turning my soul?/Oh I'm all yours!/I (when you say it) I'll not obey/Amen! I choose it I say for you.

Comment: Since this was posted I've been 90% sure that the secret to this puzzle lies in rot13(erirefvat gur genpx naq urnevat jbeqf va gur 'onpxznfxvat' (erirefrq fcrrpu). Uvag 2 frrzf gb pbasvez guvf (nyy gurfr ). Ubjrire, V nz fgehttyvat gb znxr bhg gur jbeqf! Gurer frrzf gb or fbzrguvat ng nebhaq 45f (fbzrguvat yvxr "JUB JNF VA GUR...") naq ntnva ng 1z12f va gur erirefrq genpx, ohg V'z abg fher jung...)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks for posting your comment! I obviously wasn't sure what people had tried. There's a lot of bias listening to something you've already created, and I obviously thought the vocals were better than they were. Perhaps this project was a little advanced for Grandpa Bob's vocal abilities. I'll post a vocal-only version, to see if removing the distraction of the percussion helps, and if that still doesn't help, then I'll give a big clue to get onto the final stage of the puzzle.

Comment: @Stiv Looks like I missed it, and Lanny Strack just made a big advance without the vocal-only version in the answer comments. You can probably ignore the B-side ;)

Comment: I've deleted the third hint, since I only included it because I thought that the original .mp3 file may not have been clear enough to solve the puzzle. Now that @LannyStrack has shown that the second .mp3 file is not necessary, I have removed it as it was not part of the original puzzle, and may just prove a distraction.

Comment: I think we're going to need quite a big hint to be able to solve this :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil You want it, you got it... ;)

Comment: @Anon it has been many years. ANY CHANCE?

Answer (score 8):

### Partial answer - got the CD to play!

---

By

> Taking the hexadecimal value of all the colours using a colour picker, we get the following string:
>
> 47442066696C652F642F3144634D5274794B6A5672682D68504937644B3078496B71544D77346B515373702F76696577

Next

> If we convert this to ASCII we get 'GD file/d/1DcMRtyKjVrh-hPI7dK0xIkqTMw4kQSsp/view'

So now

> The GD stands for google drive. Going to 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/1DcMRtyKjVrh-hPI7dK0xIkqTMw4kQSsp/view' we get an MP3 recording, called 'What is the title of this song.mp3', of what I assume is the song. The lyrics are the same as the lyrics underneath in the picture.
>
> It seems to be a Granpa Bob self made song, so I'm not sure where to go next. There must more hidden in the lyrics...

Also note that

> As @LannyStrack and @sarsaparilla have noticed, if you play the song backwards, the lyrics sound the same. This makes the song palindromic, but this apparently is at most a pointer for the next step.

Comment: Congratulations on getting the CD to play! But now you need to find the name of the song, which will be a little more work than the first step...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a Grandpa original too

Comment: @Anon hmm I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there just the song name to find now or is there a bit more? I have no ide what to do with the MP3 or the lyrics now, maybe someone can shed some light :)

Comment: Guvf vf jurer gur pehk bs gur chmmyr vf - fbyivat gur urk jnf n cernzoyr. V jba'g tvir nal uvagf whfg lrg ;)

Comment: Gur ylevpf ner fbzrjung hfrshy; gur erpbeqvat vf rffragvny.

Comment: @Anon I probably don’t have the software to be able to do much with the recording, not sure many will. I’m not very good with my musical understanding so I don’t know what to do next, sorry :) maybe someone else will

Comment: Gur svefg xrl fgrc znl or cbffvoyr whfg ol erpbtavgvba, be ng zbfg hfvat fvzcyr shapgvbanyvgl bs serr fbsgjner (rira vs lbh'ir arire hfrq vg orsber). Fbzr gurbergvpny xabjyrqtr jvyy or hfrshy ng n yngre cbvag gubhtu, urapr gur gnt (nygubhtu fubhyq fgvyy rffragvnyyl or fbyinoyr ol fbzrbar jvgubhg guvf xabjyrqtr). V'yy tvir n uvag n ovg yngre vs vg erznvaf hafbyirq.

Comment: The method I have been trying, but with limited success is SPOILER rot14(Psqoigs hvs kfwhhsb zmfwqg rc bch dfsqwgszm aohqv hvs gcibrg aors (obr gcibrg qob ps wbhsfdfshsr og kcfrg wb aizhwdzs komg), am hvwbywbu kog hvoh hvs oqhioz gcbu vog pssb pfcysb id wbhc wbrwjwrioz gcibrg (gmzzopzsg, pogwqozzm) obr oggsapzsr wb fsjsfgs cfrsf. Gc gkoddwbu hvs cfrsf ct soqv fciuvzm hkc-gsqcbr gbwddsh tfca ghofh hc twbwgv kwzz usbsfohs hvs fsoz gcbu. Tcf sloadzs, kvoh wg gvckb wb hvs zmfwqg og "am kwzz" ofs oqhiozzm acfs ct o rfokb-cih "aaaa" tczzcksr pm "ow". Fsjsfgwbu hvsgs hkc gcibrg, mci ush "W'a".)

Comment: @LannyStrack Vagrerfgvat bofreingvba. V guvax lbh'er zvffvat fbzrguvat gubhtu. Lbh ner pbeerpg gung gur hahfhny rahapvngvba unf n ernfba, naq fbzrjung jnez ba lbhe trareny vqrn.

Comment: @LannyStrack Nyfb gel abg gb trg gbb uhat hc ba vanpphenpvrf bapr lbh frr gur cnggrea oruvaq gur ibpnyf (guvf vf n cbvagre gb gur fbyhgvba, engure guna gur fbyhgvba vgfrys) - whqtvat ol zlfrys, V qba'g guvax Tenaqcn jnf n terng fvatre!

Comment: @LannyStrack rot13(Tvira gung Tenaqcn'f sevraq jnf bar bs gubfr 'ebpx zhfvp vf rivy' pbafcvenpl gurbevfgf, jr zvtug unir gb cynl gur zhfvp onpxjneqf gb urne n 'fngnavp zrffntr' uvqqra va vg. Nyfb, gur erpbeqf naq fbatf va Uvag 2 ner fhccbfrq gb pbagnva fngnavp, onpxjneqf zrffntrf!)

Comment: rot13(V hfrq uggcf://jjj.zc3-erirefre.pbz/ra/ gb erirefr gur zc3, ohg pna'g znxr nalguvat bs gur ylevpf. Tbg tbbfrohzcf ubjrire ....)

Comment: @sarsaparilla - Thanks!  That was actually one of the very first things I tried to experiment with when the puzzle first came out, and then I went back and tried it again when Hint 1 was first provided, but couldn't get any results that seemed to be relevant. (I use Audacity s/w.) I'll give it one more go.

Comment: @sarsaparilla - I obviously didn't do a good job listening last time I tried that technique, because when I tried it again just now, I immediately realized that rot13 (gur ylevpf fbhaq nobhg gur fnzr jura cynlrq va rvgure qverpgvba. Fb vg vf bar tvnag cnyvaqebzr. Abg fher jung anzr gb tvir vg, gubhtu...).

Comment: @LannyStrack I'm so glad someone recognized that!!!! I thought I must be going crazy! It took me so long to get the vocals to that point. I just posted a vocal only version to help people recognize that but I'll let you continue solving! There's still more of the puzzle to solve. (I also used Audacity to make it).

Comment: @Anon - In the intro you mention that Grandpa Bob may have stuck his name in there. I tried rot13 (erpbeqvat zlfrys fnlvat "Ze Qrnh" fybjyl, va gur fnzr fglyr nf gur fbat, naq gura cynlvat gung onpxjneqf. Vg'f uneq gb znxr bhg jung vg fbhaqf yvxr, ohg gur svany fbhaq fbhaqf yvxr "fnzr". Nz V ba gur evtug genpx ng nyy?)

Comment: @LannyStrack V'z abg fher gung jvyy uryc lbh. Vzcerffvir (be qrpvqryl abg) nf Tenaqcn'f cnyvaqebzvp ibpnyf znl or, gurl ner ng orfg n cbvagre gbjneqf gur fbyhgvba. Nyy V'yy cbvag lbh gb sbe abj vf zl svany fgngrzrag va uvag 3 gung gur ibpny-bayl genpx znl jryy abg or fhssvpvrag sbe gur fbyhgvba. Lbh'yy svaq uvf anzr yngre.